# How to create keybinding that reindents only selected lines in Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.14 on MacOS and have tried creating my own keybinding that re-indents **only** the lines of code that I've **highlighted**.

I have this in `keybindings.json`:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+cmd+[", "command": "editor.action.reindentlines",
        "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

I chose the commands for the `"when":` clause based on [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts).

**The Problem**: When I use my custom keyboard shortcut, it re-indents the *entire page* instead of only the text I've *selected*.

It's petty, perhaps, but this can cause a formatting nightmare, such as when writing a ReactJS app where VSC's regex pattern for detecting how to indent lines seems to get confused when looking at a mix of javascript and html within a .jsx file. In such cases I only want to re-indent/auto-indent the text I choose - not the entire page.

How can I get the keybinding to function with the behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gama11 for pointing me to this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19847#issuecomment-277348907).

The solution that accomplishes what I was trying to do is to use the command `editor.action.formatSelection` instead of `editor.action.redindentlines`.

As shown by Gama11, reindent in ranges isn't currently supported, however Format Selection is a very similar command that uses different logic to accomplish indentation within a certain range.

Answer (score 1):

The `when`-clause can only change when the command is *active* - not how it behaves. The issue is that the implementation of the command operates on the whole file, rather than the current selection.

I don't think reindentation of a selection is supported yet, but it seems to be on the roadmap. For instance, it was mentioned in [#19847](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19847#issuecomment-277348907) (emphasis mine):

> The reason that **right now we don't support Reindent in ranges** is that we have some issues with boundaries in embedded-language files. Some of them are just TextMate Grammar issues but I'm sure if that can fix all. Once that issue is addressed, I think it's easy to support reindent in ranges/selection. And then Reindent when paste/moveLines/etc.

Comment: Reading the comments on that issue was very insightful. That issue you referenced mentions another command which accomplishes exactly what I intended! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.